# Stripe::AuthenticationError -Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

Hi all guys I have a problem with the transaction on stripe.
Basically, I registered on the site and I correctly configured both the .env file with the value of the keys and the stripe.rb file in this way:

this is stripe.rb

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['INCIBUS_STRIPE_PUBLISH_KEY'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['INCIBUS_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']

}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

this is the .env file:

```
INCIBUS_STRIPE_PUBLISH_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
INCIBUS_SSTRIPE_SECRET_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

When I fill out the form in which I enter the data for the card,
makes me click on the "Pay" button and when it is loading I have an error in the controller

this is the controller:
gives me an error in the stripe_payament method:

```
class Suppliers::Dashboard::CurrentSubscriptionController < Suppliers::DashboardController
  skip_before_action :verify_supplier_subscriptions_payment
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:stripe_payment, :paypal_payment, :execute_paypal_payment]
  skip_before_action :verify_subscription_expire_date
  before_action :verify_subscription_allowance, only: [:set]

  def show
    @subscription = subscription
    @subscription_types = SupplierSubscriptionType.for_customers.select { |i| i.price >= subscription.type.price }
  end

  def set
    session[:current_subscription] = params[:id].to_i
    redirect_to suppliers_dashboard_path
  end

  def stripe_payment
  
    subscription = current_user.supplier_subscription
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      email: params[:stripeEmail],
      source: params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => (subscription.last_invoice.amount*100).to_i,
      :description => subscription.last_invoice.number,
      :currency    => 'eur'
    )

    if charge.paid
      subscription.update(expire_date: subscription.created_at + subscription.type.duration.days)
      subscription.last_invoice.update(is_payed: true, payed_at: Time.now)
      redirect_to suppliers_dashboard_subscription_path, notice: "Pagamento effettuato con successo"
    else
      render :back, error: "Errore del pagamento"
    end

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to :back

  end

  def paypal_payment
    subscription = current_user.supplier_subscription

    @payment = PayPal::SDK::REST::Payment.new(
      {
        intent: "sale",
        payer: { payment_method: "paypal" },
        redirect_urls: {
          return_url: "#{request.protocol}#{request.host}#{ Rails.env.development? ? ":3000" : "" }/produttori/dashboard/current_subscription/execute_paypal_payment",
          cancel_url: "#{request.protocol}#{request.host}#{ Rails.env.development? ? ":3000" : "" }/produttori/dashboard/current_subscription"
          # return_url: "https://www.incibus.com/produttori/dashboard/current_subscription/execute_paypal_payment",
          # cancel_url: "https://www.incibus.com/produttori/dashboard/current_subscription"
        },
        transactions: [{
          amount: {
            total: subscription.last_invoice.amount,
            currency: "EUR"
          },
          description: "creating a payment"
        }]
      }
    )

    if @payment.create
      redirect_to @payment.approval_url
    end
  end

  def execute_paypal_payment
    subscription = current_user.supplier_subscription
    @payment = PayPal::SDK::REST::Payment.find(params["paymentId"])

    if @payment.execute( payer_id: params["PayerID"] )
      subscription.update(expire_date: subscription.created_at + subscription.type.duration.days)
      subscription.last_invoice.update(is_payed: true, payed_at: Time.now)
      redirect_to suppliers_dashboard_subscription_path, notice: "Pagamento effettuato con successo"
    end
  end

  # def bank_transfer
  #   @subscription = current_user.innkeeper_subscription
  # end

  # def bank_transfer_payment
  #   subscription = current_user.innkeeper_subscription
  #   subscription.last_invoice.update(iban: params[:innkeeper_subscription][:iban])
  #   redirect_to dashboard_subscription_path, notice: "Invio coordinate bancarie effettuato"
  # end

  private

  def verify_subscription_allowance
    unless current_user.available_supplier_subscriptions.map(&:id).include?(params[:id].to_i)
      redirect_to suppliers_dashboard_path
    end
  end

end
```

this is the stack trace:

```
Stripe::AuthenticationError - No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = <API-KEY>". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface. See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.:
  stripe (1.58.0) lib/stripe.rb:159:in `request'
  stripe (1.58.0) lib/stripe/api_operations/request.rb:15:in `request'
  stripe (1.58.0) lib/stripe/api_operations/create.rb:5:in `create'
  app/controllers/suppliers/dashboard/current_subscription_controller.rb:20:in `stripe_payment'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `block (2 levels) in around'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
   () var/lib/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/route_translator-9d3350d9574c/lib/route_translator/extensions/action_controller.rb:27:in `set_locale_from_url'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:285:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `block in around'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
  searchkick (2.3.0) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:209:in `process_action'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
  actionview (5.0.7.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:727:in `call'
  omniauth (1.4.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.4.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  bullet (5.5.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in `call'
  warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
   () var/lib/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/better_errors-707ffcf284d8/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
   () var/lib/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/better_errors-707ffcf284d8/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
   () var/lib/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/better_errors-707ffcf284d8/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  railties (5.0.7.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  railties (5.0.7.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
  railties (5.0.7.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
  request_store (1.3.2) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  rack-livereload (0.3.16) lib/rack/livereload.rb:23:in `_call'
  rack-livereload (0.3.16) lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
  rack-cors (0.4.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:81:in `call'
  railties (5.0.7.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:226:in `call'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: To identify the issue can you please try using Static Credentials into `stripe.rb` something like this `Stripe.api_key =xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: trying to do this I get this error "KeyError - key not found: :ciphers:"

Comment: If possible, please update your question with the latest stack track error.